# Is there some way to get PHP to log a warning/notice/error whenever a function is being called with too many parameters?

Tags: php

I used to have this:

```
function whatever($foo, $bar, $foobar, $barfoo)
```

Later, it turned into:

```
function whatever($foo, $bar, $foobar)
```

Still, there were some instances of code doing:

```
whatever(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

That is, they were sending a fourth argument in spite of the `$barfoo` parameter having been removed.

Sadly, this was never logged as an error of any kind.

Why not? Can I enable this? Is it a bad idea for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't really care about the number of arguments, and won't consider extra arguments as an error. Regarding [function arguments](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php), PHP really is quite flexible:

> Information may be passed to functions via the argument list, which is
>   a comma-delimited list of expressions. The arguments are evaluated
>   from left to right.
>
> PHP supports passing arguments by value (the default), [passing by
>   reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.by-reference), and [default argument values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default). [Variable-length argument lists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list)
>   are also supported.

However, there are a couple of functions you can use to throw a warning in this case:

- [`func_num_args`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php) — Returns the number of arguments passed to the function
- [`trigger_error`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php) — Generates a user-level error/warning/notice message

E.g.

```
function foo( $one, $two, $three )
{
    if ( func_num_args() > 3 ) {
        trigger_error( "Too many arguments passed to function foo", E_USER_WARNING );
    }
}
```

As your goal is to find the lines where this function is still called in the old manner, it might be a good idea to add some tracing with e.g. [`debug_backtrace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php):

```
<?php
function foo( $one, $two, $three )
{
    if ( func_num_args() > 3 ) {
        $trace = json_encode( debug_backtrace() );
        trigger_error( "Too many arguments for foo: " . $trace, E_USER_WARNING );
    }
}
foo( "one", 2, "three", 4 ); // the old way, line 9
foo( "one", 2, "three" ); // current operation, line 10
?>
```

This way the warning would include the calling line & the passed arguments in JSON format:

```
AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning:  Too many arguments for foo: 
[{"file":"\\/var\\/www\\/foo.php","line":9,"function":"foo","args":["one",2,"three",4]}] 
in /var/www/foo.php on line 6'
```